# Asp.Net web api antiforgery token fails after user signin & token refresh issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, x-xsrf-token

I'm trying to make a short-lived JWT token with refresh token using Asp.Net Web API and Angular.

Though not required for the JWT and refresh token, I'm also trying to add anti forgery tokens.
The anti-forgery tokens also work until I log in.

I am refreshing the token after I've successfully signed in the user but I'm getting the error:

> The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user

If I don't log in I can do the following with the anti-forgery token:

```
GET /         ->         GET /fetch-data   ->    POST* /weatherforecasts
   ^                          200 OK                      200 OK
Anonymous token set here
```

* The Angular HttpClient does not send the token for GET methods so I changed the
   endpoint to accept POST for testing

The flow is almost the same when I try signing in.

```
GET /         ->       GET /fetch-data   ->  POST /user/login         -> POST /weatheforcasts
   ^                        200 OK           200 OK - JWT data                  400
Anonymous token set here                 refresh anti-forgery token
```

Login Method inside UserController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var emailMatch = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(login.Email);

            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(emailMatch.UserName, login.Password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var newRefreshToken = await RefreshTokenStore.MakeToken(emailMatch.Id);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("refresh_token", newRefreshToken.Token, new CookieOptions()
                {
                    HttpOnly = true
                });

                HttpContext.User = await SignInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(emailMatch); // Found from another stack overflow issue but dosen't fix the issue
                var tokens = Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions()
                {
                    HttpOnly = false
                }); 

                string token = await CreateToken(emailMatch);
                return Json(new
                {
                    token,
                    expire = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)
                });
            }
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

Inside Startup Configure I have this to set initial anonymous tokens

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
            if (string.Equals(path, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || string.Equals(path, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            )
            {
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions()
                {
                    HttpOnly = false
                });
            }

            await next.Invoke();
        });
```

The only time I got it "working" was when I removed the if statement in the app.use function and created a new token for every request but it still fails on the first request after login.

Comment: Did you find solution yet? I guess the user claims are changing, and you need to update claims before antiforgery token is generated